# How the generator in GAN works?

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to understand how GANs work, while doing so, I got stuck at how the generator network is able to generate images from the random noise input, can someone explain to me how each line is affecting the final result (i.e. an image from a random vector), especially the last three lines!

```
def build_generator():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128 * 7 * 7, activation="relu", input_dim=latent_dim))
    model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128)))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())                                    #inverse of MaxPooling
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    model.summary()

    noise = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    img = model(noise)

    return Model(noise, img)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to talk about generators in general, not specifically the one you mentioned.*

As I would like to think in GANs it's not the models that actually do the magic but the training procedure. Theoretically, you may use any architecture as you like for your generator, you can even use a simple few-layered fully connected neural nets as well, so it doesn't have to be a fancy CNN model (like ResNet, VGG, or the one you built though the fancy models have more complex representational power). What makes the generator learn to make such images is the "adversarialness" in its training procedure (kind of like the Minimax algorithm if you know about it). The fact that the generator constantly gets punished for generating noisy images by the discriminator. So the generator tries its best to create images so that it could fool the discriminator with the feedbacks (gradients) it gets.

Here is a simple GAN model that I trained:
[image: GAN model]

So you see, the architecture choice is (important) but not responsible for giving it the ability to built an image from random noise.